# Can the following molecules be called meso compounds (cyclic structures which usually exist in non-planar forms)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

> In the planar form the following molecules have one plane of symmetry.However in
>   the chair-form (the most stable form) for the first molecule and the non-planar form for the second molecule there is no plane of
>   symmetry.Will the molecules still be called meso?

BTW I do not think the molecules ever attain completely planar form.

[image]

[image]

---

Just for quick reference I'm adding the non-planar forms of the two molecules.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These molecules can never be planar. There are no internal symmetry planes and therefore they are not meso.

Comment: I've just tried building 3D models of the two enantiomers of the 1,2,4,5-tetramethylcyclohexane with my molymod kit and they are not superimposable - I tried chair, boat, half-chair and twist-boat conformations. I haven't tried the cyclooctene but I'm pretty sure it's not meso and it can't be planar, neither in cis nor trans.